# How to update deployment's initContainer image without down time in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

**kubernetes** *version*:`1.10.4`

In my project,I have an `initContainer` image and an common container image,I want to update the `initContainer`'s image with zero down time.

But the `kubectl set image xxx` command cannot work on `initContainer`.

I have read the document about rolling update containers' image, but not found the information about `initContainer` image.

Who has encountered this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do manual change I'd start with

```
kubectl edit deployment xxx
```

for non-interactive operations it's probably easiest to use `kubectl patch` like

```
kubectl patch deployment/xxx -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": {"initContainers":[{"name":"cinit", "image":"alpine:3.6"}]}}}}'
```